# How to navigate to fragment with arguments without recreating it?

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a question. I'm using nav component for navigation. For example i have fragment A, B and C and bottomNavigation. I'm using

```
binding.bottomNavigation.setupWithNavController(navController)
```

For multiple backstack. But here is situation: Main frag is A. I'm moving to fragment B or C. I have buttons on fragments B and C which should lead me to fragment A with putted arguments in it so i'm using just:

```
findNavController().navigate(fragmentBDirections.fromFragmentBToFragmentA(argument))
```

But here is a problem. I'm recreating fragment A after this but i'm already have this fragment in backstack. So is it possible to find A in backstack and navigate to it without recreating? Is it possible to save backstack after that?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem seems like an ideal case to use a [sharedViewModel](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel#sharing)

Your button in B or C should pop and fallback to A after updating a property in the viewModel. On leaving, the viewModel is not destroyed because it is bound to the activity and is available for Fragment A.

Bonus is using LiveData so that the change is observed and updated automatically

Comment: I was thinking about it but i have problem with saving backstack. Can i somehow navigate to my A fragment without pop B and C? I want something like that: A -> B -> C -> B then from B i decided to click on button so i'm heading to A with value from shared livedata but if i click navigate back on smartphone i'm going backward to B instead of pop everything from backstack and saving only A.

Answer (score 0):

I think [SavedStateHandle](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel-savedstate) might be helpful.

Comment: I will give it a try, thanks. But is there any way to make this by using nav graph?

Answer (score 0):

```
<Navigation>
<fragment
        android:id="@+id/BFragment"
        android:name="com.packageName.app.BFragment"
        android:label="fragment_b"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_b" >
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_BFragment_pop_including_AFragment"
            app:popUpTo="@id/AFragment"
            app:launchSingleTop="true" />
</Navigation>
```

```
<Navigation>
<fragment
        android:id="@+id/CFragment"
        android:name="com.packageName.app.CFragment"
        android:label="fragment_c"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_c" >
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_CFragment_pop_including_AFragment"
            app:popUpTo="@id/AFragment"
            app:launchSingleTop="true" />
</Navigation>
```

try it . it's my solution

Comment: It will save only fragment that we left from right? I mean we don't saving our backstack "history" right?

Comment: can not understand. it likes stack C-B-A   if C-A the stack just has A  if C-B the stack has B-A. The fragment lifecycle is onPause() -> onResume

Comment: yeah i mean if it's B->C->A it's only C from A on backstack but not B. It's not fully saving backstack